# login with facebook, facebook give me other id

Tags: facebook

i try to do a login with facebook, i build this code:

```
    <?php
ob_start(); 
include("facebook_constants.php"); // in this file i have appid and appsecretid

$users = $facebook->getUser();

if ($users!="") {   
  try {


    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me','GET'); 

    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    $fuserid=$user_profile["id"]; // give me the id of the user
    $fusername=$user_profile["name"]; // give me the name of the user
    $femail=$user_profile["email"];  // give me the email of the user

    $fusernamenew = str_replace(' ', '', $fusername); // change the name to username (omer lol = omerlol)

    $newtoken=base64_encode($fuserid."::".$fusernamenew."::".$femail); // data to token

    $itsme = $this->haimz->DB->num_rows("SELECT id FROM users WHERE fbid = ?haimz?", $fuserid); // if have user with that id = login , if not goto register page

    if($itsme > 0){
echo "goto login page";
    }
    else{       
echo "goto register page";
        exit;
    }

  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $users = null;
  }
}
?>
```

the $fuserid give me other userid but the $fusername and $femail give me the correct .
its not the userid of the user.
its other userid.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

> To better protect people's information, when people log into a version of your app that has been upgraded to use Graph API v2.0, Facebook will now issue an app-scoped ID rather than that person's orginal ID. However, for users that have previously logged into your app, the user ID will not change.

You don´t get the "real" ID of a user anymore, for privacy reasons. You only get an App Scoped ID that is unique in the App only. You can still use it to identify the user when he returns to your App with the App Scoped ID, it will only be different in another App.

You can also map App Scoped IDs between different Apps with the Business Mapping API, if needed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Comment: what permission? there is no way to get the "real" id anymore.